# ona to many relation last record wrong because null date

Tags: mysql, relational-database, one-to-many

Having a one to many relation on tables accounts and accounts_prop I try to fetch the last property of an account with the last date(bis),

Having the following query returns records but there is a problem when date is equal with `0000-00-00` then the before date is calculated as the max date

```
SELECT  c.account_id, p.bis
FROM    accounts as c INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  account_id,
                    MAX(bis) MaxDate
            FROM   accounts_prop
            where accounts_prop.bis != 0
            GROUP BY account_id
        ) MaxDates ON c.account_id = MaxDates.account_id INNER JOIN
       accounts_prop p ON   MaxDates.account_id = p.account_id
                    AND MaxDates.MaxDate = p.bis
```

How do I exclude records where last bis date is equal with `0000-00-00`

Comment: You are unclear. Please explain in detail. Eg we couldn't write code from being told "fetch the last property of an account with the last date". Read & act on [mcve]. We should be able to run it & get your output given your input, & what is desired output. Tell us what an arbitrary row in each table says about the business situation in terms of its columns, & constraints on tables.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a DATE data type

From MySQL Doc [B.5.4.2 Problems Using DATE Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-date.html)

> The special “zero” date '0000-00-00' can be stored and retrieved as
>   '0000-00-00'. When a '0000-00-00' date is used through Connector/ODBC,
>   it is automatically converted to NULL because ODBC cannot handle that
>   kind of date

I suggest that you try one of the following for your subquery :

```
SELECT  account_id,
        MAX(bis) MaxDate
FROM   accounts_prop
where accounts_prop.bis > '0000-00-00'            
GROUP BY account_id
```

or

```
SELECT  account_id,
        MAX(bis) MaxDate
FROM   accounts_prop
where accounts_prop.bis IS NOT NULL            
GROUP BY account_id
```

Comment: thanks for feedback tried all of the variants but still having problem on null dates, I'm using mariadb